# Google Event Tracker v3

Tags: android, google-analytics

I've a problem with the google Event Tracker.
Following the official documentation [Google develop Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/events) i add the xml file with my id.
After on the activity i create a new Tracker, and try to push a new event, but the method "sendevent" does not exist.

this is my code

The import:

```
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.Tracker;
```

//I think i've to only import the tracker

and the simple code

```
 Long opt_value;
          Tracker MyTracker;
           MyTracker.sendEvent("ui_action", "button_press", "play_button", opt_value);
```

And the error:

```
The method sendEvent(String, String, String, Long) is undefined for the type Tracker
```

Thank's to all and sorry for my bad english

Edit:
Now i'm tryng with

```
  MyTracker.send(MapBuilder
      .createEvent("evt",    
                   "Id",    
                   ""+idSong,       
                   null).build()
  );
```

but on logcat i have:
08-20 10:45:35.320: I/GAV3(5371): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use sendEvent method you should first initialize the tracker like:

```
private static Tracker m_GaTracker;
private GoogleAnalytics m_GaInstance;
m_GaInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context);
m_GaTracker = m_GaInstance.getTracker("UA---");
m_GaInstance.setDefaultTracker(m_GaTracker);
m_GaTracker.sendEvent("your value ", " ", " ", 0L);
```

The above code works with V2 lib  , to work with V3 use:

```
  // Instead, send a single hit with session control to start the new session.
    mTracker.send(MapBuilder
      .createEvent("UX", "appstart", null, null)
      .set(Fields.SESSION_CONTROL, "start")
      .build()
    );
```

Comment: <string name="ga_trackingId">
i put the trackid on the analitycs.xml file

Comment: with your code i've the same error..
The method sendEvent(String, String, String, long) is undefined for the type Tracker

Comment: I am using Google Analytics V2 jar file

Comment: it's possible that the error is because i don't call   EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); on start?

Comment: I am also not using EasyTracker in my code, I am just using the code I pasted above in my answer and Google Analytics V2 works just fine for me

Comment: I have edited my code ,check if this works, alternatively provide me ur email id so that I can send u jar file.

Comment: on your profile i can't see your mail address.
I've triyed with your code, but there're the same error.
Can send the file at brancato.ga (@) gmail (.) com
thanks a lot!

Comment: How to use it in V3 jar, because V2 jar can't be download from google website?