# Implement Google Analytics for Android LibGDX Game Screens

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, libgdx

I´ve encountered a problem with implementing Google Analytics on a LibGDX Game App. I want to track the screens of the game, but Google Analytics works only in the android folder part of the Gradle project. In the core part, it doesn´t get the Context for the game screen classes, although I´ve added the libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar to the core folder also. 
I´ve searched for solutions over the internet, but nothing worked out so I cannot initialize Google Analytics in the core part of the project.

This is a code snippet where I try to initialize Google Analytics:

```
GoogleAnalytics GA = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance();
```

and it gives me this error “ The type android.content.Context cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files ”

Should I use the libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar of the Android project in the Core also or should I use another jar file for this task?

Below are some links where I found information for this issue.

[Google Event Tracker v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329997/google-event-tracker-v3)
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/migration
http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=4298

Any answer on this specific issue would be very useful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the Google Analytics sdk **only** in the android project, not in the core project. In the core project should only be platform-independent code. Don't import android libs into your core project.

If you want to track a screen view within core project you should can achieve that by using an interface. There is a [wiki guide for interfacing libgdx](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code)

Your interface for tracking screen views could be something similar to this:

```
public interface Trackable {
   public void trackScreen(String screenName);
}
```

In your android project this method would then implement the Google Analytics tracking code.

Answer (score 2):

If your using Intellij / Gradle based project add Google Play Services to your project like so:

1. Add the `google play services` dependency to the gradle file in your android project. (Before this you should get the latest version from SDK Manager)

   dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
   }
2. Add `Internet` and `Network State` permissions to your manifest file.

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   ```
3. Change min sdk to 9 in your manifest file.

   `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />`

Now you need to add GA to your game, you can follow the steps here: http://pygmalion.nitri.de/google-analytics-sdk-v4-with-libgdx-536.html or on GA's main site.